# Can somebody check my code? User ID data not showing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Can somebody tell me where I got the error in my code? I already tried different queries in my get_userdata method and I even tried $query->result_objec(); but so far I've been unable to display the correct info.

```
public function user($id){
    //Check Login
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_member')) {
        redirect('dashboard/login');

    } else {

    // Get user info
    $data['item'] = $this->User_model->get_userdata($id);


    // Load template
    $this->template->load('public', 'default', 'users/user', $data);

    }
}
```

and then my method on my User_model:

```
public function get_userdata($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $query =  $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is my view in which I need the info from the model to be displayed. I'm using `$query->row()` because in the view I'm using $row->item:

```
<section class="showcase text-center" style="background: url(<?php if($item->cover_img) : echo $item->cover_img; else : echo base_url().'assets/img/nocoverimage.gif'; endif ?>)no-repeat center center; background-attachment:fixed;">
<div class="container">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="<?php if($item->avatar_img) : echo $item->avatar_img; else : echo base_url().'assets/img/noavatar.jpg'; endif ?>">
    <h1><?php echo get_user_full_name($item->user_id); ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $item->occupation; ?></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline btn-lg">Follow</a>
</div>
```

I already tried using $query->result() and $query->result_object(); and I still get the error of **Trying to get property of non-object** then I decided to use a different query to get arrays instead of objects.

For example `result_array()` and `row_array()` should work with something like $row['somevalue'] , right?; well I'm still getting the same error.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: is `$query->num_rows() > 0`?

Comment: Are you getting the id OK var dump it and make sure is OK

Comment: I would say that it does(yes) because if I go to a different user profile (in the browser bar) it shows the username of the user.id in the URL what it does not shows is the rest of the info. I want to say that I get a bool(false) when I var_dump the variable in the controller method. I dont know why it shows the correct user URL but not his info.

Comment: `User_model` loaded?

Comment: change `return $query->row();` to `return $query->result();` in your **User_model**.

Comment: @Kevin You've been shown how to debug this stuff in previous answers to your previous questions. Might be an idea to go and look at those plus people are mentioning them here again... Use var_dump and trace back through your code... For starters check your SQL and what does var_dump($data) give you?

Comment: used $this->db->last_query to echo the sql query of yours and with that query used in phpmyadmin is it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

On User_model change the `where` clause to using `'user_id'` instead of `'id'` (on your view you are using `$item->user_id` to get the user full name) :

```
public function get_userdata($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id); // change to user_id

    $query =  $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```